# I have 10 database tables 6 of them being link tables, should I make a general LinkTable?

Tags: database, database-design

I have 10 database tables `A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I` and `J`. Four of them are necessary, but six of them are just link tables that link between those four tables. I am considering building a generic link table for this so

```
A, B, C, D, Link
```

Performs the same way as before except that the Link table provides all linking what the old six tables used to do. I need three columns for the Link table (subject, target, type).

Do you think this makes sense or is a sensible approach?

If it makes any difference, the size of the Link table should not get big. The `type` column is `TINYINT`. One of the link subjects is `User`, and that pretty much defines how big the entire link table can get. There will be some what 5% more rows in the table than there are rows in the `User` table.

Comment: The Force to generalize is strong with this one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, no I wouldn't do this.

Yes, it might look "excessive" to have six link tables for four base data tables. But really: do you gain from having just a single link table, but then you have to start adding a type to the link (it's a link from table A to table D or something else), and it all gets rather messy.

To me, the clarity of being able to **see** that two tables are linked, because there's a link table between them, is much more important than having one or two tables fewer. That really doesn't make a big impact in any way - neither in terms of disk space, nor in terms of performance is this going to be beneficial.....

So again: why bother? Have a clear and proper design, and just accept the fact that relational databases need a few helper tables between their main tables to make the "magic" work - and don't worry too much about that fact.....

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll consider your thoughts.